# MIT Kerberos for Windows w/ PuTTY & AD (MSLSA)

Tags: windows, active-directory, hive, kerberos, putty

I run a Linux environment that's setup in an MIT Kerberos Realm.  That realm has a one way trust setup that allows tickets for AD principals (from Windows 7 clients) to be accepted as authentication (for SSH and ODBC for Hadoop/Hive).

The problem I'm having is that Windows 7 clients using Kerberos for Windows 4.01 do not seem to be able to use their AD ticket in MSLSA.  If I set KRB5CCNAME to a file and obtain an AD ticket independently of MSLSA everything works fine.  With KRB5CCNAME set to MSLSA: it does not work.  I did find a note about setting AllowTGTSessionKey to 1, but that's already been done (and rebooted).

Is there a way to use the AD tickets stored in MSLSA using MIT KfW?

Answer (score 1):

Try to set `hkcu\software\mit\kerberos5 string:ccname value:MSLSA:` then
delete the `krb5ccname` variable and log off and on.